# Delay javascript code before executing the next line

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a situation whereby i need to delay/stall the code a little before the next line of code will be executed.

```
    elementslist1[Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)].click()
    elementslist2[Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)].click();
    elementslist3[Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)].click();
    elementslist4[Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)].click();
    elementslist5[Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)].click();
    elementslist6[Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)].click();
    elementslist7[Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)].click();
    elementslist8[Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)].click();

    var input = document.getElementById('inputelement');
```

I need the code to delay for sometime after 
`elementslist8[Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)].click();` has executed.Then after this delay it can now proceed to the next line which is

`var input = document.getElementById('inputElement');`

Comment: use setTimeout?

Answer (score 0):

So use a queue with a timeout

```
var elems = [elementslist1, elementslist2, elementslist3, elementslist4]

function clickNext() {
  // grab first item from queue
  elems.shift()[Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)].click()
  // if array still has items
  if (elems.length) {
    window.setTimeout(clickNext, 2000)
  }
}

// start it
clickNext();
```

Comment: ,there is still no delay between elementslist8 and the following line.

Comment: Well you need to put the logic in there.... After the i`if (elems.length) { } else { /*logic here */ }`

Comment: i cannot understand.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible in JavaScript.

You can use `setTimeout` though, it will be more complex than what you're asking though.

Comment: UnemplOyedd,how complex?

Comment: Annoyingly complex.